# Message Template receive gives Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: spring-integration

This is my spring-integration inbound and out bound which gets a list from a end point.

```
<http:inbound-gateway id="webListGateway"
        request-channel="fromWeb_List" 
        reply-channel="toWeb_List" 
        path="/api/profile/V1/get"
        supported-methods="GET">
       <http:header name="container" expression="#pathVariables.container"/>
       <http:header name="groupName" expression="#pathVariables.groupName"/>
       <http:header name="userId" expression="#pathVariables.userId"/>
      </http:inbound-gateway>

    <int:header-enricher input-channel="fromWeb_List" output-channel="toCloud_List">
        <int:header name="apikey" value=“1234”/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <http:outbound-gateway id="profileListGateway"
        request-channel="toCloud_List"
        reply-channel="sync_preferences"
        url=“localhost:8081/containers/{container}/groups/{groupName}/values/hierarchy/{userId}"
        http-method="GET"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        charset="UTF-8"
        extract-request-payload="false"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        encode-uri="true" >
        <http:uri-variable name="container" expression="headers.container"/>
        <http:uri-variable name="groupName" expression="headers.groupName"/>
        <http:uri-variable name="userId" expression="headers.userId"/>
    </http:outbound-gateway>
```

This is my recipient-list-router which send backs the list to requestor and also saves the list in another end point.

```
<int:recipient-list-router id="syncRouter" input-channel="sync_preferences">
     <int:recipient channel="toWeb_List"/>
    <int:recipient channel="toCloud_Save"/>
</int:recipient-list-router>
```

I am also trying to call the outbound gateway from java code and trying to get the response from toWeb_List channel by using receive method on MessageTemplate, which is giving me error

```
MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
        Message<String> message1 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("")
                .setHeader("container", “fwd”)
                .setHeader("groupName", “foo”)
                .setHeader("userId", “user”)
                .build();
        template.send((MessageChannel) CONTEXT.getBean("fromWeb_List"),message1);
        PreList pre = (PreList) template.receive((MessageChannel)CONTEXT.getBean("toWeb_List"));
```

error

```
Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:springboot.toWeb_List'
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `DirectChannel` for the `MessagingGateway.receive()`:

```
protected final Message<?> doReceive(MessageChannel channel, long timeout) {
    Assert.notNull(channel, "MessageChannel is required");
    Assert.state(channel instanceof PollableChannel, "A PollableChannel is required to receive messages");
```

Another issue that `reply-channel="toWeb_List"` has to be registered as `correlator` in the Inbound Gateway to be able to receive messages, as Gary pointed. And that is done on demand, on the first request. That's why you get 
that `Dispatcher has no subscribers`.

And really, please, try to explain what you would like to do.

**UPDATE**

If you are going to reuse that `<int:recipient-list-router>` from the HTTP Inbound and from some other similar request-reply place, you should consider to drop off usage of the `reply-channel` and just rely on the `replyChannel` in headers.

I mean there can be that `toWeb_List` channel bean definition, but should not use it from the `reply-channel`. In this case your config should be like this:

```
<int:recipient-list-router id="syncRouter" input-channel="sync_preferences">
     <int:recipient channel="toWeb_List"/>
    <int:recipient channel="toCloud_Save"/>
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:bridge input-channel="toWeb_List"/>
```

The `bridge` is such a components to shift message from input channel to the output one, if present. Otherwise it consults `MessageHeaders` for the `replyChannel` value. And this is is populated exactly via those Inbound request-reply components such as `<http:inbound-gateway>` or plain `<int:gateway>` when you call directly from Java.

See more information in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-default-reply-channel).

Comment: when I make a http request to inbound it works fine as it has subscribers. when i call from with in system using java I am not going through inbound, instead directly from header enricher to outbound. Is there any way to send the response back to java caller without going through inbound request.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Integration is awesome, used the bridge and then template.sendAndReceive, its working. Thanks a lot for ur quick responses.